# Problema para conectar com o banco de dados no SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot

Quando tento startar minha aplicação, apresenta o erro:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Action:

Consider the following:
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Não entendo o que está acontecendo, uma vez que configurei corretamente o application.properties, e as dependências estão corretamente instaladas.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banco_de_usuarios

# 1 - usuário do banco
spring.datasource.username=root

# 2 - senha do banco
spring.datasource.password=admin

# 4 - dialeto 

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

Meu pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.br.criandoapi</groupId>
    <artifactId>projetoApi</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>projetoApi</name>
    <description>Projeto Api Teste</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Como resolver?

Comment: Você tem o Mysql instaldo e rodando localmente na sua maquina na porta 3306?

Answer (score -2):

Seria interessante verificar o banco de dados que vc está passando pela URL ("spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/banco_de_usuarios") foi criando no MYSQL previamente, para isso acesse o SGBD que você está usando (MYSQL OU XAMPP), insira o comando `create database nomeDoBanco;'`. Verifique se a senha e nome de usuário foi corretamente definido. Aparentemente não tem erros nas dependências, pode ser cansaço mesmo.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Verifique se essa sua senha e usuário são os que estão configurados no MySQL e tente fazer o nome da tabela sem o _

Comment: O username e senha estão corretos, alterei o banco de banco_de_usuarios para apenas usuarios, mas continuou dando o erro.